# throwError makes other Test Cases fail in Angular 6

Tags: angular, unit-testing, observable, karma-jasmine

I have `Angular` service call in component, which returns observable, if there's http error it throws in component too:

```
private loadData(): void {
    this.someService.getdata(filter)
      .pipe(
        catchError((error: any) => {
          this.loadingError$.next(true);
          return throwError(error);
        })
      ).subscribe(
        (data:any[]) => {
          this.records = data;
        }
      );
}
```

in the test case I'm trying to make it throw exception to cover `catchError` code part, I have the following TC:

```
it ('should handle error', (done) => {
    const err = new Error('fake error');
    spyOn(someService, 'getData').and.returnValue(throwError(err));

    component.loadingError$.subscribe((error) => {
        expect(error).toBe(true);
        component.loadingError$.unsubscribe();
        done();
    });

    component.ngOnInit();
});
```

Method `loadData` is called from `ngOnInit`.
I put `debugger` after expectation and result is correct, But this TC is causing other TC's failing randomly..

Any idea?

Comment: I am guessing that the spy should return `HttpErrorResponse` not `Error`. But not sure what your `throwError` function does. If it throws an Error then may be you should catch it in test with a try/catch.

Comment: @sabithpocker it helped, thank you!